# Anonymizing Magento 2.3 DB with fake data

Tags: magento2, database

I have tried to anonymize my Magento 2.3 DB with fake data and tried several tools. They are either too complicated or not working ...

Anyone knows of a good tool or way to replace all data with working fake data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this one? https://github.com/elgentos/masquerade

I'm no developer but even I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write scripts for it. There are several tuts available for creating products,order,customer etc. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need data for testing, you can install sample data, two options:

1. ---> Sample data module, simply run composer command to install sampledata:
   To install sample data using the command line, enter the following command as the Magento file system owner in the  folder:

   bin/magento sampledata:deploy

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html

2. ---> Generate profiles for performance testing:

To use the Magento Performance Toolkit or another tool for performance testing, you must generate a large amount of data (for example, stores, categories, products, and so on).

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try GDPR dump but it needs some configuration... Would be nice if you share your config if you succeed.
 https://github.com/machbarmacher/gdpr-dump